# Trouble finding CDF from PDF

Tags: probability, self-study

I am trying to solve some of my past papers exam and really don't know where I did wrong here :

[image]

Naturally, I know that the integral from minus infinity to infinity for any pdf equals $1$. 
I solved this :

$$\int_1^a\frac{\ln(0.5)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=1$$

But when I did, I came with a value of a smaller than $1$ which is not possible... ($a=e^{-1/\ln(2)}=0.27$)
I really don't get where I did wrong.
Obviously when I tried to find the CDF by integration, I found something weird too...

Comment: note that $log(.5) <0 $ and $\int_1^a = - \int_a^1$

Comment: @aginensky But we are told $a \ge 1$! The fact is that since $\log(0.5)\lt 0,$ $f$ cannot possibly be a probability density for positive $x$--but we are also told $x \ge 1.$

Comment: well then $log(.5) <0 $ I'm saying the problem is wrong- final answer.

Comment: I think you miscalculated. I get approximately 1.275

Comment: I did it by hand first and found 0.237. Wolfram Alpha and my calculator gave me the same answer.

Comment: That's what I call a stumper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have started with drawing this *alleged* PDF:

[image]

It's [always negative](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/140655-the-hardest-thing-of-all-is-to-find-a-black) in $x\in[1,\infty)$. Just a couple of weeks ago someone was [asking here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333421/is-probability-theory-the-study-of-non-negative-functions-that-integrate-sum-to) whether the probability is the study of nonnegative functions.

Someone was having hangover when coming up with the problem :)