# Are there really many continous distributions without the PDF

Tags: distributions

This is one interesting question I take some time to search if there is any distribution function that is continuous but without the PDF.

After some search I found [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution), sometimes referred as the Devil's staircase according to Wikipedia.

The reason why I am asking this question are some comments I got from one member of this website saying there are many of these.

There are some distributions like [lambda distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey_lambda_distribution) with if statement inside the PDF which may be what he was referring.

I am also not sure if he assumed some conditional distributions in which case it may be the PDF is possible unknown.

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455668/defining-continuous-random-variables-via-uncountable-sets) and its links.

Comment: I like your link and specifically a part where it reads "Such singular distributions are not common in statistics". Thank you @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: So as not to cherry-pick, I'm quoting the full sentence here: "Such singular distributions are not common in statistics (except as counterexample), but are ubiquitous in other areas."

Comment: Also see @kjetilbhalvorsen's comment at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298293/absolutely-continuous-random-variable-vs-continuous-random-variable/298434#comment567156_298434.

Comment: @whuber to me, this link doesn't answer this question, I do not see in there concrete link to any particular distribution without PDF. I hoped someone will answer what does it mean that the distribution doesn't have the PDF. I have the strong pre-conviction that statisticians really need continuous distributions with PDF so that they can express and calculate `d*`, `p*`, `q*` functions in R for instance. Without that this would not be possible.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask for an example; but if you want one, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103969.

Comment: This was an example to the discrete RV. In my understanding discrete variables do not have PDF. I don't think PDF is the same as PMF, but I don't know much on that topic. I may be wrong.